# USB topology - difference in tiered star and spanning tree

Tags: usb

I am studying about USB and in the USB2.0 documentation it is written to follow a tiered star topology. While specification for USB4.0 says the topology is spanning tree. Are the two equivalent? Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the difference is that the logical topology no longer matches the physical topology – the logical "spanning tree" can be a *subset* of the physical connections, as in section 2.2.2.

USB 2.0 enforced the star topology using physical connectors: the host always had type-A ports, which always went into type-B ports (and supplied power in that direction). For example, if you had a USB hub, you could chain more hubs from it, but you couldn't connect its "output" back to the same host, nor could you connect two hosts. And even with hubs, data could only flow between a device and the host – never between two devices directly, so the host was naturally the center of the star.

Meanwhile, with USB4 you get bidirectional type-C ports everywhere, and both the "host" role and the power supply direction are negotiated dynamically, so star topology is [no longer enforced](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/D1T1-3%20-%20USB4%20System%20Overview.pdf#page=16) – physically it can be a mesh and the Connection Manager's job is to prune that mesh into a tree. Additionally, the USB4 spec heavily uses such terms as 'fabric' and 'router', so it looks like it's literally a *communications network* that carries USB3 inside, and not just a straight-up USB3 replacement.

So in other words, probably the same reason why modern Ethernet isn't really a "star" network anymore – while previously it had a stricter topology, with designated rx/tx wires and uplink & downlink ports, nowadays that's no longer the case. For example, you can connect Ethernet switches in a ring and they'll use STP/RSTP to agree on a spanning tree (which can dynamically rearrange itself, even to the point of electing a new root).